# Why am i getting "No Such Table" when running SQL query with cursor.execute()?

Tags: django, sqlite

I am trying to run a simple sql query but i keep getting "Operational Error: No Such Table customers" The code in question is:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM customers")
# cursor.fetchone() or cursor.fetchall()
r = cursor.fetchone()
print(r)
```

Whats weird is running a raw SQL query using the code below works and i'm able to iterate through the rows and display in HTML:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM customers"
customer = Customer.objects.raw(sql)[:10]
print(customer)
print(connection.queries)
```

When i probe into SQL explained in the debug_toolbar for the 2nd code above that worked, I get which looks correct:

```
Executed SQL
SELECT *
  FROM customers
Time
1.1129379272460938 ms
Database
network_db
```

Also whats weird is the django docs says to add the app name so when adding the app_name `network` into the 2nd code, i get an error saying
`no such table: network_customers` but the code works if i remove the app name as per the 2nd code. See the app name included into the 2nd code:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM network_customers"
customer = Customer.objects.raw(sql)[:10]
print(customer)
print(connection.queries)
```

Databases in settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default':{ 
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    },
    'network_db':{
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'Network.sqlite3',
    },
    'simulation_db':{
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'Simulation.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

Network apps.py:
from django.apps import AppConfig

```
class NetworkConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'network'
```

So i'm wondering why is the 2nd code working but the 1st code is not? I've checked the debug_toolbar which shows the BaseDir is where the database i'm querying is located so i dont think thats an issue.

## SOLUTION

I was able to fix the 2nd code by specifying the location of the database where the table is using the code below. I still have not figured out why my select statement is working without me specifying the app name like `select * from appname_tablename"`

```
database='C:/EXACTLOCATION/../../Network.sqlite3'
db=sqlite3.connect(database)
c=db.cursor()

sql_command='SELECT * FROM customers'
customer = c.execute(sql_command)
customer = c.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same error as you and managed to figure it out.
As you specified multiple databases in `settings.py`, you need to initialise your cursor as such:

```
from django.db import connections
with connections['network_db'].cursor() as cursor: # use the alias of the database specified in settings.py
        cursor.execute("select * from appname_tablename")
        data = cursor.fetchall()
```

if you only have one database in  `settings.py`, you initialise your cursor as such:

```
from django.db import connection
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("select * from appname_tablename")
        data = cursor.fetchall()
```

Can refer to the django documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/sql/)